# Go defer function return values

Tags: go

```
func main() {

    println(DeferFunc1(1))
    println(DeferFunc2(1))
    println(DeferFunc3(1))
}

func DeferFunc1(i int) (t int) {
    t = i
    defer func() {
        t += 3
    }()
    return t
}

func DeferFunc2(i int) int {
    t := i
    defer func() {
        t += 3
    }()
    return t
}

func DeferFunc3(i int) (t int) {
    defer func() {
        t += i
    }()
    return 2
}
```

Above code will print: `4 1 3`. Can anyone explain this? Of course, `DeferFunc1` should return `4`. But why will `DeferFunc2` and `DeferFunc3` will return `1` and `3` respectively? Is that about closure or variable scope in Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `DeferFunc1` makes sense to you then `DeferFunc3` should as well as they illustrate the same concept, namely that you can modify a named return value.

In `DeferFunc1` you are adding 3 to 1 in your defer yielding your expected 4.
In `DeferFunc3` you are adding 1 to 2 in your defer yielding 3.  A naked return here, or a return of t would get you to 4.  But in this case, `t` is assigned the value of 2 right before your defer runs, so you get 3.
In `DeferFunc2` you are not using a named return, so you cannot take advantage of this technique.

Comment: Oh thank you! Now I think I know how defer function named return value work!